# Dropbox API How to Set Content-Type in RestRequest

Tags: dropbox-api

Trying to call Dropbox API v2.

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/")
Dim request = New RestRequest("files/search", Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & MYTOKEN)
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
'request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
'request.JsonSerializer.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;"
 'request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/json")
 request.AddParameter("path", "")
 request.AddParameter("query", "my file")
 request.AddParameter("start", "0")
 request.AddParameter("max_results", "1")
 request.AddParameter("mode", "filename")
 Dim res = client.Execute(request)
```

Always return

```
Error in call to API function "files/search": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Expecting one of "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack"
```

Tried the commented code lines but still the same response. Any clue?

Comment: Guessing from the code, but is this Visual Basic and are you using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

If my guesses are right, and this is Visual Basic code using RestSharp, then I think you need something like this (apologies if it's not quite right; I don't know VB syntax):

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/")
Dim request = New RestRequest("files/search", Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & MYTOKEN)
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request.AddBody(New With {
    .path = "",
    .query = "my file",
    .start = 0,
    .max_results = 1,
    .mode = "filename"
})
Dim res = client.Execute(request)
```

Comment: Pretty close, I had to make a json object and then call request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this. There could be better ways to do it but this works for now.

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/") 
Dim request = New RestRequest("files/search", Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & MYTOKEN)
 request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")  '---> this line still doesn't seem to do anything

Dim json As New JObject(New JProperty("path", ""), New JProperty("query", "my file"), New JProperty("max_results", 1), New JProperty("mode", "filename")) 
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody)
Dim res = client.Execute(request)
```

Dropbox API appears to be very sensitive as for example, the object in AddParameter cannot be a json string, it must be json object. And "1" say in max_results doesn't work, it must be 1 without the quotes.  A lot of trial and error but finally worked.